# Check if entry exists in database with custom validation constraint

Tags: php, symfony, validation, symfony-forms

So in my Symfony application I have an Entity called `Post`.

My Post Entity has the following properties:
`post_start`,`post_end` and many more.

**ENTITY:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 */
class Post
{

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var DateType
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $post_start;

    /**
     * @var DateType
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyPath="post_start")
     */
    private $post_end;

.....
}
```

**FORMTYPE:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add(
            'post_start',
            DateType::class,
            [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control input-inline datepicker',
                    'data-provide' => 'datepicker',
                    'data-date-format' => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                ]
            ]
        );

        $builder->add(
            'post_end',
            DateType::class,
            [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control input-inline datepicker',
                    'data-provide' => 'datepicker',
                    'data-date-format' => 'dd.mm.yyyy'
                ]
            ]
        );

        $builder->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'save post',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-success')
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Post::class
        ]);
    }
```

When I submit the form, I want to check if the database already has an entry with the same startdate and enddate and of cource from the same user.

```
1. If YES -> Show error message 
2. If NO -> Create post request.
```

When the entry already exists, but it's from a different user, just go ahead and create the post.

I wanted to do that with a custom validator constraint. But what happens next I have to somehow compare the data with each other

**ContainsEqualDate:**

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ContainsEqualDate extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Post request is already exists.';

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

**ContainsEqualDateValidator:**

```
class ContainsEqualDateValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * @var ORMUserRepository
     */
    private $userRepository;

    /**
     * @var ORMPostRepository
     */
    private $postRepository;

    /**
     * @param ORMUserRepository $userRepository
     * @param ORMPostRepository $postRepository
     */
    public function __construct(ORMUserRepository $userRepository, ORMPostRepository $postRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->postRepository = $postRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the passed value is valid.
     *
     * @param mixed $value The value that should be validated
     * @param Constraint $constraint The constraint for the validation
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {

 $userId = $this->getUser();

    $postExists = $this->postRepository->findBy(array(
        'post_start' => $value,
        'app_user_id' => $userId
    ));
}

/**
 * @return User
 */
private function getUser(): User
{
    return $this->storage->getToken()->getUser();
}
    }
     }
```

Comment: Instead of passing Repositories in __construct method, just give it an entity manager. EntityManager $em.

And then you can access the desired entity through em.
$this->em->getRepository('ApiBundle:Post')->findBy(array(
        'post_start' => $value,
        'app_user_id' => $userId
    ));

Comment: @Archi That's what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Max Trui, you have not mentioned how are the User and Post entities are related in your database.

If you have UserId in Post Entity, you can do Following.

```
$userId = $this->userRepository->getUser()->getId();
$entryExists = ($this->postRepository->findBy(array('post_start' => $value, 'user_id' => $userId)) == null) ? true : false;
```

you can replace 'post_start' with the dynamic fieldname value(post_start or post_end), which you can provide from where you call validator.

If you want to check for both dates at the same time, provide both values in validator.

Comment: `!= null` is enough :), no need for `false : true`

Comment: I have updated my Question. What do I have to do with the findBy because I can't find this method. Same with $postExists...?

Comment: @MaxTrui findBy is the default doctrine method.  You can also try findOneBy but that may fail if you have more than one records for given userId and date.

If you find no results from post entity for provided parameters, $postExists will be true otherwise it will be false and your validation will fail saying entry exists.